# How can I parse integer values into separate int variables from a comma separated string?

Tags: c++, string

I have a string that contains 3 numbers separated by commas (for example "10,32,52") and I would like to store each number in 3 different int variables, but I just know how to store the first one using the code below. Can you tell me please how can I store the next two?
Thanks in advance.

```
string numbers= "10,32,52";
string first_number_s= numbers.substr(0,2);
int first_number_n= stoi(first_number_s);
```

Comment: Do you really need separate integer variables? Using a `std::vector<int>` for the integers may be a better choice.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stream the input string into a string stream and use std::getline to extract strings separated by a delimiter, in this case comma, converting each one to an integer:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string numbers = "10,32,52";
std::istringstream sstream(numbers);
std::string temp;
std::vector<int> nums;
while (std::getline(sstream, temp, ','))
{
    nums.push_back(std::stoi(temp));
}
```